# Change position of tags in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

```
<p>I like turtles</p>
<h3>Child brags about stuff</h3>
<h4>The Herd</h4>
```

How do I change the positions (order) of a tag?

To this:

```
<h3>Child brags about stuff</h3>
<p>I like turtles</p>
<h4>The Herd</h4>
```

Is there a JQuery possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.detach()` and `.insertAfter()` jQuery methods, like so:

```
$(function() {
   $('p').detach().insertAfter('h3'); 
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76HGL/) proof.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
$('h3').after($('p'));
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/ZHkaH/).

Comment: I forgot that `.after()` moves the element if it is already in the DOM. Nice and succinct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `h3` in the variable `h3elem` and the `p` in `pelem` (get them there however you want - jQuery, `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName`, or anything really), use:

```
h3elem.parentNode.insertBefore(h3elem, pelem);
```

This moves the `h3` to before the `p`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doWorks(){

    var h3 = $("h3");

    h3.remove();

    h3.insertBefore("p");


}
```

Comment: Why not use the h3 variable in the second line?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will insert `<h3>` tag before `<p>` tag, you can assign them an id to identify them uniquely.

`$('h3').insertBefore($('p'));`